# Facing issue in LeetCode Compiler but works in IDE

Tags: java

Code:

```java
  public class twoSumSolution {
     public int findFirstlocation(int[] a, int target) {
      for (int i = a.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        int temp = a[i];
         for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
          if (a[j] + temp == target) {
          return j;
        }
      }
    }
    return -1;
    }

    public int findSecondlocation(int[] a, int first, int target) {
    int holdtemp = a[first];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
      if (holdtemp + a[i] == target) {
        return i;
      }
    }
    return -1;
     }
    }

     public class TwoSum {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] nums = new int[] {
         11,
         2,
         15,
         7
      };

     int target = 9;
     twoSumSolution s = new twoSumSolution();
     int firstindex = s.findFirstlocation(nums, target);

     int secondindex = s.findSecondlocation(nums, firstindex, target);

     System.out.println("[" + firstindex + "," + secondindex + "]");
     }
    }
```

Error in LeetCode Compiler:

```
Line 7: error: cannot find symbol [in __Driver__.java]
      int[] ret = new Solution().twoSum(param_1, param_2);
                      ^
  symbol:   class Solution
  location: class __DriverSolution__
```

Index output works well in any IDE such as Netbeans or Eclipse , but fails in leetCode compiler can  someone guide me?Error is at line 7

Comment: You've used a class called `Solution`, which you haven't shown here, and which probably you haven't given to the leetcode compiler.

Comment: It looks like LeetCode expects a class called `Solution` with a default constructor and an instance method `twoSum(...)`, which you did not provide.

Comment: The Leetcode framework expects your class to be called Solution. You've invented a new name it doesn't know.  Just change it back.  Also delete other classes.

Answer (score 0):

Leetcode has the following solution signature which you should not change, that means you don't need to define the main function. Each leetcode problem comes with a default solution signature which you need to fill out with your solution, if you change the signature itself it will give you error.

eg. below is the default signature for the two-sum problem for Java. Assemble your code inside this twoSum function to make it work. You can add your functions if you need as shown.

```
class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        // TODO: fill this out.
    }

    // eg. functions you can put inside the solution class.
    public int findFirstlocation(int[] a , int target)
    {
        for (int i=a.length-1 ; i>0 ; i--)
        {
          int temp = a[i];
          for(int j=0 ; j<i;j++){
              if (a[j]+temp ==target){
                  return j;
              }
          }
            
        }
     return -1;   
    }
    
    
    public int findSecondlocation(int[] a , int first ,int target)
    {
      int holdtemp = a[first];
      for(int i=0 ; i<a.length ; i++){
          if (holdtemp + a[i]==target){
              return i ;
          }
      }
     return -1;   
    }
}
```